# using the .Change() with dropdownlistFor (want to add the values selected to another div as text)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to add the values you select in a dropdownlistfor as text inside an div. Trying to implement this with Jquery, but as I'm totally new to this, I can't seem to get it to work.

**Dropdownlistfor code:**

```
<p>
   @Html.Label("Departure route:")
   @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Departureroute, Model.RoutesList, new {@class = "dropdownlist", @id = "departureroute"})
</p>
```

I have assigned it with an id = departureroute.

**Js code**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$("#departureroute").change(function () {
  var str = "";
  $("#departureroute option:selected").each(function () {
      str += $(this).text() + " ";
  });
  $("informationcontent-outbound").text(str);
  }).change();
</script>
```

The div i want this text to appear is "informationcontent-outbound"

Hope someone can see what is wrong here.

Comment: `$(".informationcontent-outbound")` or `$("#informationcontent-outbound")` ?

Comment: Not sure.. its not a class or id.. its an div.. should i add an id to that div?

Comment: Exactly. It must have be valid selector..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to use `this.value` for getting selected value, no need to use `each()`. Also your div selector is not valid

```js
$("#departureroute").change(function() {
  $("#informationcontent-outbound").text(this.value);
  //-^--------- if class then use '.'
}).change();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id=departureroute>
  <option value=1 selected>1</option>
  <option value=2>2</option>
  <option value=3>3</option>
</select>
<div id="informationcontent-outbound"></div>
```

Comment: Somehow your code don't work with the dropdownlistfor.. but it does work with the select list.

Answer (score 0):

[**Working Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/Iceburg/ppq9dvyg/2/)

depends on the informationcontent-outbound Div

```
//Using Id Selector
 $("#departureroute").change(function () {
   $("#informationcontent-outbound").text(this.value);
    //If informationcontent-outbound is an Id use above line
   $(".informationcontent-outbound").text(this.value);
    //If informationcontent-outbound is a class use above line
 });

//Using Class Selector
$(".dropdownlist").change(function () {
   $("#informationcontent-outbound").text(this.value);
    //If informationcontent-outbound is an Id use above line
   $(".informationcontent-outbound").text(this.value);
    //If informationcontent-outbound is a class use above line
 });
```

Comment: it works with an select list.. but not dropdownlistfor.

Comment: as far as you are having id as "departureroute" this should work